# How do I setup a constantly listening loop with receiving udp sockets without making it a server?

Tags: java, c++, udp

I have a C++ server and java clients, the C++ server constantly sends udp packets to the clients to let each client know whats going on with the other clients, but there is a complication. I do not want each user to have to forward their port in order to setup a constantly listening udp loop, is there a way I can avoid this in java? Also when the server receives a udp packet, I get the data in "from" (sockaddr type), and I use this to get the ip: from.sin_addr.s_addr but it always only gets my local ip, 192.168.1.1, is there a way to receive which external ip it came from?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. The clients will have to use a fixed port
2. They will have to advise the server of their port number and indeed their IP address
3. You could use multicast.

Comment: Normally you'd punch a hole in NAT gateways by simply sending an UDP packet, and have the server reply to the source address/port in the packet you get. i.e. point 2 just means have the client send a packet to the server first, and the server sends it packets back there.

Comment: @nos Exactly. I'm not sure what the perceived difficulty is here.